# Activation Time iOS Developer Program

Tags: ios

How long does the activation of the iOS Developer Program? So, how long does it take after you have purchased until you have access to iTunes Connect and your apps can upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually takes about between 24 hours and a few business days. I'm in the United States,  I suspect it might take a little longer if you have to fax in international paperwork and the like.

Once your account is activated, be sure to take care of your contracts in iTunes Connect.

Patience is a virtue. If you're always rushing to push out apps, you're going to end up releasing buggy software. Take a deep breath and have a coffee or a beer. The folks at Apple will activate your account soon.

Comment: oke, takes it also with credit card paying 24 hours?

Comment: It should be the same, no matter how you pay.

Answer (score 0):

It will take a maximum of 24 hours. It depends a lot. Do a search and you will find many other questions similar to this.